Making the selections in Radio Set Widget of Textual.io more prominent
When I am creating a RadioSet widget for my application, I am finding the distinction pretty weak for the selection made and the other options. Is there a way I can make the selected option more prominent?
The below picture of the tcss snippet have the settings I use for the RadioSet.
I have tried using width, height and color styles in the tcss file, but it does not affect the size and color of the circular checkboxes.


The following was deduced by inspecting the default css in my .venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/textual/widgets/_radio_set.py.
You can adjust colours of various elements as follows:
RadioButton.-selected {
    background: blue;
    color: red;
}

RadioButton.-on > .toggle--button {
    background: red;
    color: yellow;
}

RadioButton > .toggle--button {
    color: yellow;
    background: green;
}

If you put that into say radio.tcss then the following basic app.py will let you test this out with textual run app.py --dev (--dev lets you edit the CSS while the app is running and see the changes):
from textual.app import App, ComposeResult
from textual.widgets import RadioSet, RadioButton


class RadioApp(App):
    CSS_PATH = "radio.tcss"

    def compose(self) -> ComposeResult:
        with RadioSet(id="radio-set"):
            yield RadioButton("Option 1")
            yield RadioButton("Option 2")
            yield RadioButton("Option 3")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    RadioApp().run()


Option 2 is selected, Option 3 is toggled on.
